# How do I get the s3BucketName from CDK bootstrap without creating an asset?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk, bucket

How can I get the s3 bucket name from the bootstrap stack?

I cant seems to find any other method than creating a dummy asset and get the s3BucketName attribute.

--
Update:

I have two stacks:

Stack 1: Creating a bunch of S3 assets.

Stack 2: Creating an IAM policy to give access to the assests created in Stack 1 (no assets)

I need to lookup the bootstrapped assets bucket in Stack 2 to be able to add the resources attribute in my IAM Policy

I find multiple solutions for this, but all of them seems hacky

The CDK framework can reference the bucket when instantiating new assets, without me providing the bucket name, this implies that the framework know the bucket name, hence it must be possible for me to get hold of it and avoid either hardcoding, creating dummy assets or using Fn::Import when adding the resources attribute in my IAM Policy in Stack 2

Comment: I may have described my problem to wague, and have updated the question

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question, you can get the asset bucket name through the DefaultStackSynthesizer:

example:

const assetBucketName = cdk.DefaultStackSynthesizer.DEFAULT_FILE_ASSETS_BUCKET_NAME

Comment: Unfortunately that returns `cdk-${Qualifier}-assets-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}`, which is not very useful...

Answer (score 0):

[Toolkit reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cli.html#cli-ref)

```
cdk bootstrap --toolkit-bucket-name <bucket name>
```

Comment: Well this implies that i hardcode the bucket somewhere. The internals of the cdk know the bucketname without i have to provide it.